# diff command with regex (bash)

Tags: regex, bash, diff

I want to see if 2 files are different. If they are I want to output something. If not, output something else. This is the code I use and it works fine

```
if diff file1.txt file2.txt >/dev/null ; then
  echo "Not different"
else
  echo "Files are different"
fi
```

However, now I want to add conditions to my `diff` such as:

```
| grep "<" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | sed '/#/d'
```

How do i add this regex in my diff command so that my `if statements` will work??

Thank you

Comment: What exactly you are trying? What does `grep "<" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'` do?

Comment: `grep "<"` just prints the line that's different and `awk '{$1=""; print $0}'` removes the extra < that diff prints

Comment: You might want to look into the various options that `diff` provides for specifying its output, rather than post-process the default output.

Comment: @Matin You don't need to pipe `diff` output to `grep`, `awk`, and `sed` to find the lines that have changed in file1.  Using `comm` is simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the result of your operation.

```
r=$(diff file1.txt file2.txt | grep "<" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | sed '/#/d')
if [ -z "${r}" ] ; then
```

Edit: You were checking for output, not for error code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But my real question was how and where do I add the regex...?

Comment: There is no regex given, you've state some addition to the original command.

Comment: I did that and I get this error

`test.sh: line 31: [: too many arguments`

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to point you in the right direction, not write complete valid code. ;) The code is now updated and should work as expected. At least it works with my test files.